# WPF Toolkit Datagrid - how do you turn selection off?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpftoolkit

I have a datagrid in WPF that I am binding to an object.

I have a DataGridCheckBoxColumn on there which I want the users to be able to go through and tick the ones they want. Problem is they have to click twice, once for selection then again to check/uncheck. How on earth do you turn this off, I've been searching for way to long to find the answer to this. The datagrid has SelectionMode and SelectionUnit properties - neither of which accept 'none' or 'go away'

Any help is appreciated! My code is below for reference

```
<my:DataGrid Margin="15"  Name="dgPreview" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True" 
             CanUserDeleteRows="True" 
             Background="White" 
             ColumnHeaderHeight="20" 
             VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
             RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" 
             >

    <my:DataGrid.Columns>
        <my:DataGridCheckBoxColumn  MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Header="Include" Binding="{Binding Include}" />
        <my:DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50"  Width="Auto" Header="Override #" Binding="{Binding OverrideNumber}" />
        <my:DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="220" Width="*" Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
        <my:DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  Header="Preview" Binding="{Binding Preview}" />
    </my:DataGrid.Columns>
</my:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Newer question on this topic, with many good answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833536/how-to-perform-single-click-checkbox-selection-in-wpf-datagrid/8333704#8333704

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first click puts the cell in edit mode then the second click allows you to modify the checkbox.  You can change this behavior by using a DataGridTemplateColumn instead of a DataGridCheckBoxColumn.  Replace your DataGridCheckBoxColumn with this:

```
<my:DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="50" Width="Auto" Header="Include" SortMemberPath="Include">
   <my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource DataGridCheckBoxStyle}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Include}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </my:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</my:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

DataGridCheckBoxStyle just makes the CheckBox look a little nicer in the DataGrid:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}">
   <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8,0,3,0" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in WPF 4.0. Thanks for the style though. :)

Comment: Works for me in WPF 4.0. However, I get a warning while compiling and in the designer for the "BasedOn"-Tag in the style: `The Resource "{x:Type CheckBox}" was not found` I just removed it and it stil works.

Comment: Per prior comment remove Style reference. Should look like:                 <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="60" Header="Migrate" SortMemberPath="Checked">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Checked}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>

Answer (score 1):

First of, I know this is a pretty old question but I still thought I'd try and answer it.

I had the same problem a couple of days ago and came across a surprisingly short solution for it (see [this blog](http://tapiocacom.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/checkbox-on-datagrid-with-single-click.html)). Basically, all you need to do is replace the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` definition in your XAML with the following:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyCheckBoxColumnHeader">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyViewModelProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The upside of this solution is obvious - it's XAML-only; thus it effectively refrains your from burdening your code-back with additional UI logic and helps you maintain your status in the eyes of MVVM zealots ;).

Comment: It's the same answer as the one above.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  The above didn't work for me in the sense that clicking a check box didn't actually change the underlying objects.   I believe the fact that you added in the Mode=TwoWay fixed that issue.